# Hide DIVs after function has completed his task

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a piece of code that auto replies to user text input.
An automated "live chat" so to say.

Though when the script runs out of responses I want it to disable the subit form and button, I don't really have any clue on how to do such a thing.

My code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#typing").hide();
      var n = "You:<br>";
      var o = $('#outputWindow');
      var i = $('#inputWindow');
      var s = $('#sendButton');
      var t = $('#typing');      
      var r = -1;

      //arrays
      var msg = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3'];

      //fire send events
      $(s).click(function() {
      runAI();
      });
      $(i).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            runAI();
      }
      });

      function runAI() {
      if (i.val().length > 0) {
            r = r + 1;
            o.html(o.html()+n+$("#inputWindow").val()+"<br><hr>" );      
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").show();  }, 3000);            
            setTimeout(function(){ o.html(o.html()+"Username:<br>"+msg[r]+"<br><hr>") }, 7000);
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").hide();  }, 8000);
            i.val('');
            i.focus();
      }
      }
      i.focus();
    });
});//]]>  

</script>
```

The idea is to hide the submit form and button after (in the case) the script has responded with: msg1, msg2 and msg3.

If anyone can help, that'd be great !

Comment: Why just don't check for the value of `r` after you output your message? When `r == msg.length` you just hide both `i.hide(); s.hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do that. Place at the bottom of the `runAI()` function.

this will check `r+1` each time `runAi()` is invoked. When it detects that it's greater than or equal to the message array length it will hide the user input possibilities after the last message is sent.

```
  function runAI() {
     if (i.val().length > 0) {
        r = r + 1;
        o.html(o.html()+n+$("#inputWindow").val()+"<br><hr>" );      
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").show();  }, 3000);            
        setTimeout(function(){ o.html(o.html()+"Username:<br>"+msg[r]+"<br><hr>") }, 7000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#typing").hide();  }, 8000);

        if (r+1 >= msg.length)
        {
           $('#inputWindow').hide();
           $('#sendButton').hide(); 
           return true; // end the function here;
        }
        else
        {
           i.val('');
           i.focus();
        }
     }
  }
```

When `r` reaches a length greater than or equal to the length of the array the input and button is hidden.

Comment: @Snowlav, see update. Ideally you want to timeout the hiding too with 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply use CSS to hide it:

```
$(<your object>).css('display', 'none');
```

use this for every object you want to hide. Go to www.w3schools.com and check out the posible values for the `display` property.